# How to open a Facebook chat window from a canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-chat

Is it possible to open a facebook chat window to a specific person from within a canvas app?

I have read through the FB.ui() functions and can't find any way to do it. I do not want to send any messages but merely open the window to allow users to send chat messages themselves.